# Safari column-count Bug

Tags: html, css, safari, column-count

So i found this Bug in Safari but cant find a solution to fix it.

```css
.menu ul{
  column-count: 2;
}
.menu ul li{
     width: 257px;
    height: 35px;
}
.menu ul a{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
     width: 257px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""></a>was</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>something</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>dtzdnj</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>was</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>something</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>dtzdnj</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>was</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>something</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>dtzdnj</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

so the left side is perfectly clickable but the right is not because the elements are not really on the right side.

[This Image shows the problem while hovering an element which should be on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DMDV.jpg)

Comment: why did you put a position absolute on the a element and you've sent them away from their position?

Comment: the project im working on requires me to allow the user to click on the whole "button" instead of just the text.
also there is a image which is located outside the <li> element and has to be located relative to a parent element ... this is why i cant use position:relative on the <li>

Comment: then put another div inside the li, ot in alternative you can achieve the click on the whole button by using `display:block` on the `a` element

Comment: Yes this was the solution thank you :)
[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lzrrbd)

Comment: I put it in my answer... ok?

Comment: yes please :) thank you

Comment: Done, thank you for choosing my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same but without `position: absolute` and `z-index:999` for  the `a` elements and adding `display:block` to `a` element

```css
.menu ul{
  column-count: 2;
}
.menu ul li{
     width: 257px;
     height: 35px;
}
.menu ul a{
 display:block;
     width: 257px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""></a> was </li>
    <li><a href=""></a> something </li>
    <li><a href=""></a> dtzdnj </li>
    <li><a href=""></a> was </li>
    <li><a href=""></a> something </li>
    <li><a href=""></a> dtzdnj </li>
    <li><a href=""></a> was </li>
    <li><a href=""></a> something </li>
    <li><a href=""></a> dtzdnj </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: shure this would work but i need the a tag seperated from the text also the a tag has to be absolute otherwise it would affect the text